# Dynamically calculated description of a midje fact

Tags: testing, clojure, midje

I want to write a function to factor out some common facts, like this

```
(defn check-odd-and-positive
  [n]
  (fact (str n " not odd") n => odd?)
  (fact (str n " not positive") n => positive?))

(facts "about the answer"
  (check-odd-and-positive 42))
```

But it doesn't result in "42 not odd" as the description of the fact.  I know a similar effect could be achieved with tabular facts, but I want to be able to share such a fact among fact groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, it's quite simple with [metadata](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Metadata#defining-metadata) as of midje 1.6

```
(fact {:midje/description (str n "not odd")} n => odd?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with a macro here

```
(defmacro check-odd-and-positive [n]
  `(fact ~(str n " not odd") n => odd?)
  `(fact ~(str n " not positive" n => positive?))
```

However, midje includes the tested value in the report, so I cannot clearly see why this is necessary at all.